# firefox ublock for html5 jwplayer popover

Tags: firefox

trying to block annoying popover whenever jwplayer paused. direct picker/zapper fails.  deleting node solves problem until next vid/page load, obviously.  ublock origin 1.15.10

firefox inspector outer html:

```
<div id="jwa" style="width: 300px; height: 250px; display: block; top: 200px; left: 425px; position: absolute; z-index: 10; visibility: visible;">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="main">
            <iframe src="https://website.url/stuff1/stuff2/blah.html?rnd=123.456" style="border: none;" scrolling="no" height="250"
                frameborder="0" width="300"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="remove" data-ready="Close this ad" data-timing="Please wait for {0} seconds" data-count="5">Close this ad</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

inspector path:

```
html > body.watching > div#wrapper > div#body-wrapper > div#movie.container >
div.widget > div#player > iframe > html > body.embed > div#player > div#jwa
```